# Is there any open source library for rendering doc, xls, ppt and pdf to html code?

Tags: rendering, document, html-rendering

I would like to write a "quick look" feature for my web application, that allow user "view" these kind of document on the web page, how can I do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use OpenOffice which can open all of those formats. OpenOffice can also be used to convert a document to HTML. All that can be done through a Java API on the server (no GUI required).

I do not know how good the generated HTML is though, but it might be worth trying.

For PDF you will need an OpenOffice plugin that enables OpenOffice to open PDFs (for editing).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Crocodoc API](http://crocodoc.com/api/). [Crocodoc](http://crocodoc.com/) provides an HTML5 viewer (no Flash!) which you can embed in your web pages. It's free for non-commercial use.